# Spring validation annotations (@Size, @NotEmpty, @Max...) not working in my MVC project

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, hibernate-validator

I'm trying to get my head around an MVC project. There is a form page that the user fills out and they end up in an object of the Employee class.

```
 @RequestMapping("/ask")
    public String askDetails(Model model) {

        model.addAttribute("employee", new Employee());

        return "ask-page";
    }
```

Here is what the class part looks like. It can be seen that I set parameter validation above some of the fields.

```
import jakarta.validation.constraints.*;

...

public class Employee {
    @Size(min = 2, message = "Name must be min 2 symbols")
    private String name;
    @NotBlank(message = "surname is required field")
    private String surname;
    @Max(value = 100,message = "max is required field")
    private int salary;
    ....
}
```

Here's what the html page looks like with the form filled out. It can be seen that the form **"errors"** is used to catch errors.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>

...

<form:form action="show" modelAttribute="employee">

    Name <form:input path="name"/>
    <form:errors path="name" />
    <br>
    <br>
    Surname <form:input path="surname"/>
    <form:errors path="surname"/>
    <br>
    <br>
    Salary <form:input path="salary"/>
    <form:errors path="salary" />
    ...
```

Well, this is how the method looks like, which redirects to another page if all the fields in the form have been validated.

```
@RequestMapping("/show")
    public String showDetails(@Valid @ModelAttribute("employee") Employee emp, BindingResult bindingResult) {

        System.out.println("surname length = " + emp.getSurname().length());
        System.out.println("name length = " + emp.getName().length());
        System.out.println("bindingResult.hasErrors() = " + bindingResult.hasErrors());

        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "ask-page";
        } else {
            return "show-page";
        }
```

The problem is that the annotations specified above the fields in the class do not work. Here is the output of the **showDetails** method, which shows that data is being entered that does not match the specified restrictions in the **Size, Name** annotations. You can also see that **bindingResult** indicates no errors.

```
...
surname length = 0
name length = 0
bindingResult.hasErrors() = false
```

Does anyone know why these annotations don't work?

In my view, validation should not pass and the user should be returned the original form with an error on incorrectly filled fields

UPD.
POM.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.pablinho.spring.mvc</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring_mvc</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
  <name>spring_mvc Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>6.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      <version>6.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-beans -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
      <version>6.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>6.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jstl -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

<!--    <dependency>-->
<!--      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>-->
<!--      <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>-->
<!--      <version>2.5</version>-->
<!--    </dependency>-->

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/servlet-api -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.5</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.servlet/jakarta.servlet-api -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>6.0.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-validator -->
<!--    <dependency>-->
<!--      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>-->
<!--      <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>-->
<!--      <version>6.1.0.Final</version>-->
<!--    </dependency>-->

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-validator -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
      <version>8.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.validation/jakarta.validation-api -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.2</version>
    </dependency>


  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>spring_mvc</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

UPD. Add web.xml, applicationContext.xml and conroller MyController.java

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">

  <display-name>spring-cource-mvc</display-name>

  <absolute-ordering />

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.pablinho.spring.mvc" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <bean
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

MyContoller.java

```
package com.pablinho.spring.mvc;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import jakarta.validation.Valid;



@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class MyController {

   
    @RequestMapping("/ask")
    public String askDetails(Model model) {

        model.addAttribute("employee", new Employee());

        return "ask-page";
    }


    @RequestMapping("/show")
    public String showDetails(@Valid @ModelAttribute("employee") Employee emp, BindingResult bindingResult) {

        System.out.println("surname length = " + emp.getSurname().length());
        System.out.println("name length = " + emp.getName().length());
        System.out.println("bindingResult.hasErrors() = " + bindingResult.hasErrors());

        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "ask=page";
        } else {
            return "show-page";
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Which Spring version are you using? As you are using `jakarta.validation` in your code you need either to use Spring Framework 6 or downgrade to an older version of the validation api that has the `javax.validation` packages and not the JakartaEE ones. As a note those aren't Spring Validation annotations but are from the standard Validation API which has nothing to do with Spring itself.

Comment: I am using version 6.0.2.

<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>6.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
 
I tried using the annotations from the javax package but the result was the same.

Comment: Then you probably have only the API and not the `hibernate-validator` dependency which is needed.

Comment: This dependency is also in pom.xml

  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
      <version>6.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

Comment: Please add your pom and configuration you might have. You need the hibernate validator version 8 or up, as version 6 is for JavaEE and not JakartaEE.

Comment: Tried version 8 of hibernate-validator, same result.


Added to description pom xml

Comment: Spring itself is using 7.0.5 instead of 8, so you could try that. If that doesn't work somethingin your configuration must prevent the creation of the validator. Please add some configuration and also add your full controller as well (instead of only the method).

Comment: The 7.0.5 version didn't help either. Attached in the description config files and controller class.

Comment: You are deploying as a WAR to which server are you deploying this?

Comment: apache-tomcat-10.0.27